# Searching with sql statement with either or

Tags: sql-server

I would like to search a product either by name, price or username of the seller, if one of these is not select, for example if only name is insert, the statement look for all item which has this name and if i precised more information such as price, the item look among the item which name has been insert and look for the item with current price

i have arrived at this point but still i can't do more can you help please

```
Declare @endate datetime ,
        @name varchar(50),
        @cat varchar(50),
        @to varchar (50),
        @from varchar(50),
        @user varchar(100),
        @con varchar(100)

        AS
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  Top(6)
            Item.ItemID,
            Auction.AuctionID,
            Item.Name,
            Item.Description,
            Item.Quantity,
            Item.Condition,
            Category.CategoryName AS Expr1,
            Auction.EndDate,
            Auction.CurrencyValuePost,
            Image.Image,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item.ItemID ORDER BY Item.ItemID ASC) AS RN
    FROM Item
    INNER JOIN Category ON Item.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
    INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID
    INNER JOIN Seller ON Item.SellerID = Seller.SellerID
    INNER JOIN Member ON Seller.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Image ON Item.ItemID = Image.ItemID
    WHERE   Auction.Status = 'BID'
    And Auction.EndDate > @endate
    And Category.CategoryName = @cat
    And Item.Name = @name
    And CurrencyValuePost BETWEEN @from and @to
    And Item.Condition = @con
    And Member.Username = @user
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In your WHERE Clause you can do something like:

```
WHERE 
     (@name IS NULL OR Item.Name = @name)
AND 
     (@cat  IS NULL OR Category.CategoryName = @cat)
AND
     (@user IS NULL OR Member.Username = @user)
AND 
     (...any additional clauses)
```

Comment: Beware that indexes will not be used for any of the columns involved in those OR clauses.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your query should look like:

```
Declare @endate datetime ,
        @name varchar(50),
        @cat varchar(50),
        @to varchar (50),
        @from varchar(50),
        @user varchar(100),
        @con varchar(100);


SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  Top(6)
            Item.ItemID,
            Auction.AuctionID,
            Item.Name,
            Item.Description,
            Item.Quantity,
            Item.Condition,
            Category.CategoryName AS Expr1,
            Auction.EndDate,
            Auction.CurrencyValuePost,
            Image.Image,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item.ItemID ORDER BY Item.ItemID ASC) AS RN
    FROM Item
    INNER JOIN Category ON Item.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
    INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID
    INNER JOIN Seller ON Item.SellerID = Seller.SellerID
    INNER JOIN Member ON Seller.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Image ON Item.ItemID = Image.ItemID
    WHERE   Auction.Status = 'BID'
    And Auction.EndDate > @endate
    And (@cat = '' or Category.CategoryName = @cat)
    And (@name = '' or Item.Name = @name)
    And (@con = '' or Item.Condition = @con)
    And CurrencyValuePost BETWEEN @from and @to
    And Member.Username = @user

) AS T
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: IT IS SAYING SYNTAX ERROR ')'